# Status after each argument passed to -exec in find

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a quick script to list all the files in a directory, run a function on each of them, and then print out the status code. Now the status code I would like is of the entire transaction and not the last expression that was executed. For example...

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt -exec my_function {} \;
```

Let's say I have the following files `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt` in my directory. When `file1.txt` gets passed to `-exec` its status code is `1` but calls to `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` return `0`. When I call `echo $?` at the end it returns `0` from the last expression executed despite the call on `file1.txt` returning a `1`. What I would like is a status code that's nonzero if any of the expressions return a nonzero value in the above script just like what was described for `file1.txt`. How would I go about that?

Comment: The exit status from `find` is `0` if it processes all the files correctly. The status from the `-exec`ed command doesn't factor in. So I don't think you can get `find` to do what you want, as such. You need to manually handle this sort of thing. The return status from the `-exec`ed command *might* work with `find` argument conditionals though. You might be able to use that to do something like what you want.

Comment: Hmm, that seems like that may be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest something like this:

```
status=0
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
   my_function "$file"
   ((status |= $?))
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -print0)

echo "status=$status"
```

This will print `status=1` if any of the exist status is `1` from `my_function`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I wasn't sure if there was a way to do what I was trying to do on a single line. The reason for that is the line exists within a `yml` file and I was seeing if it was possible to do something similar to what you've written without having to call out to a file. But it looks like I may have to do it like this. Thanks again!

Comment: This will need BASH, make sure you're running it in BASH only

Comment: Thanks! I have `#!/bin/sh` not `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt  -print0 | xargs -r0 -I {} sh -c "echo {}; echo $?;"
```

Following the suggestions received from `lcd047`, in order to avoid issues with names containing `"`, a better solution is

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt  -print0 | xargs -r0 -I {} sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$1"; echo $?' sh {} \;
```

Comment: This fails if you have files with names containing `"`.  Do it like this instead: `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt  -print0 | xargs -r0 -I {} sh -c 'echo "$1"; echo $?' sh {} \;`.  Better yet, replace the first `echo` by `printf '%s\n'`, to avoid problems with filenames starting with `-`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (tested with GNU find), which will print a line out for each file for which the exec returns non-zero status:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" '(' -exec my_function {} \; -o -printf 1\\n ')'
```

You could use the `-printf` to print something more informative, like the filename. But in any case, there will only be output if `my_function` fails for some file. (Or if it prints something.)

Answer (score 0):

Although `-exec ... \;` only returns the exit status as the truth value of the primary, `-exec ... {} +` causes the `find` invocation to return non-zero exit status if any invocation returns a non-zero exit status (and always returns true as a primary, since one invocation may handle more than one file).

If `my_function` handles multiple arguments, then

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt -exec my_function {} \;
```

will do the job.

If not, you could do

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt -exec sh -c 'r=0; for arg do my_function "$arg" || r=1; done; exit "$r"' sh {} \;
```